# JS AJAX to post generated file as PDF to server directory

Tags: javascript, ajax, pdf

I have a complex table generated via javascript that I'd like to save as PDF on the server. I've looked around at the pdf generation libraries and they all seem to be limited in terms of style, fonts, etc (that's what I meant by 'complex'). The table can be download client side as PDF or printed.

Let's say my function that generates the form to be printed is `reportBody(data);` - is there a way I can use `AJAX` to send the document as PDF to a php file that will save it server-side instead of downloading it client-side? The `reportBody(data)` is a collection of other variables, function calls etc.

So basically the question is - since we can generate a PDF file client-side, can we POST it (the pdf) via ajax to the server?

Comment: What don't you understand? Are you asking whether it's possible to send bytes to a server? Are you asking whether it's possible for server-side code to save a file?

Comment: I'm asking if I can post a generated file via ajax to the server as a PDF.

Comment: You can post data via AJAX, regardless of whether it happens to be a PDF or anything else.  What don't you understand?

Comment: I know you can post data via ajax - I wanted to know how to post data that is already PDF or PDF ready format to avoid doing conversion in the backend - hence avoiding use of php-pdf libraries. Perhaps you never understood the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is Yes. Your provided information is still limited as it's not clear what is ran in the `reporBody(data)` but most PDF libraries on client side are able to give you the PDF file as base64 encoded data in form of a string. 
You can then simply send that string to the server and save that as a PDF file.
A simple implementation will be something like this:

```
// I have used jQuery for convenience but you can use any lib or Vanilla JS         
var saveData = $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: "url-to-the-php-script",
          data: { pdfData: 'base64StringDataHere'},
          dataType: "JSON",
          success: function(resultData) { alert("Save Complete") }
    });
```

Then on server side, do something like this:

```
$pdfData= $_POST['pdfData'];    
file_put_contents('filename.pdf', base64_decode($pdfData));
```

Comment: Thanks, this solutions seems promising. The `reportBody(data)` is basically more js variables, objects and function calls. I've implemented this before for images - I never thought I can also have a base64 string PDF. I'll definitely implement this.

Comment: You can encode/decode almost any file/data via base64. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are a lot of ways. One would be, if you have html code in your reportBody(data); you could:

- Send the html to a php file via ajax
- in this php you could use https://wkhtmltopdf.org/ to generate a pdf file
- In the client side you could point to that pdf generated

Comment: The `reportBody(data)` is purely js variables, objects and functions - that is called at run time and generates the form

Comment: Ok, then you need to convert that information in html. You could pass this information and build the html in the html that is argument to a wkhtmltopdf because that scritp execute javascritp, or you could build the html in the client and pass it as argument in a php script to generate the html file which will serve as argument to wkhtmltopdf. wkhtmltopdf works like wkhtmltopdf http://example.com/myfile google.pdf